# Cannot install plugin in Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, plugins, joomla, configuration, paytm

I need to install **paytm** plugin in my Joomla project. But when I try to install it throws an error like `JFolder::create: Could not create directory
Warning: Failed to move file!`.

It is a live site, so I'm not sure what is happening.

Recently this site moved from one server to another,  and I checked the **tmp_path** in Global configuration:
In the old server it is set to `'/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs//tmp'` and
in our new server it is set to `/var/www/vhosts/test.example.com/public_html//tmp`

Is there any mistake in **tmp_path**?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Change tmp_path and log_path to

```
public $log_path = './logs';
public $tmp_path = './tmp';
```

in cofiguration.php file